# Classes vs Funções Construtoras / Funções Fábrica

Tags: javascript

Estou aprendendo js e não sei qual a diferença entre criar função construtora e criar uma classe, alguém consegue me explicar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em Javascript tudo é feito a partir de objetos. O método mais comum de criar e instanciar objetos é utilizando uma função. Por exemplo:

```
function Carro (marca, cor) {
    this.marca = marca;
    this.cor = cor;
    this.imprimir = function() {
        return this.marca + ' ' + this.cor;
    };
}
```

O método das classes foi introduzido na versão ES2015. Inclui a palavra "class" e permite definir o método "constructor".

```
class Carro {
    constructor(marca, cor) {
        this.marca = marca;
        this.cor = cor;
    }
}
```